# Three.js browser compatibility

Tags: three.js

I was reading the Three.js wikipedia page and it states "Three.js runs in all browsers supported by WebGL." If you use canvas renderer will the application/game created with Three.js run in browsers that support canvas but not webGL. Also are there any know issues with Three.js and mobile browsers.

Comment: You're actually more likely to have hardware support issues. Some older Macbooks for example don't have a graphics card which support GL

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually all browsers are supported which have support for canvas. We do not support polyfilled canvas. Mainly because most of the time, we use other things beside the canvas that are not implemented by the browser.

Answer (score 10):

Checkout the browser compatibility list here:

> http://caniuse.com/webgl

There's another site with a pretty neat breakdown of the OS + device/browser combination support for WebGL:

> http://webglstats.com

Edit: To answer your second question on mobile, problems will be unlikely if the mobile browser supports WebGL since WebGL is basically based off of Open GL 2.0 ES (Embedded Systems).  "ES" is mainly targeted things like mobile devices

Comment: So that's: IE 11+, & Chrome 18+. Safari & Firefox browsers seem to only have partial support at the time of writing :(

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [WebGL plugin](https://github.com/iewebgl/iewebgl) for Internet Explorer 10 and below.